# html method=get not passing values to the next aspx page

Tags: html, vb.net, get, methods

i have simple html page with 3 textboxes.

```
<form id="form1" method=get action="http://mysite.com/default.aspx" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="name" type="text" value="Amy" />
        <input id="email" type="text"  value="amy@jf.com"/>
        <input id="phone" type="text" value="2125552512" />
    </div>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Now when it loads default.aspx i have this code in the vb backend on page_load.

```
Dim tbName As TextBox = Page.FindControl("Name")
Dim tbPhone As TextBox = Page.FindControl("Phone")
Dim tbEmail As TextBox = Page.FindControl("Email")
If page.request("name") & "" <> "" AndAlso tbname IsNot Nothing Then
    tbname.text = page.request("name") 
End If
If page.request("email") & "" <> "" AndAlso tbEmail IsNot Nothing Then
    tbEmail.text = page.request("email") & ""
end If
If page.request("phone") & "" <> "" AndAlso tbphone IsNot Nothing Then
    tbPhone.text = page.request("phone") & ""
End If
```

The page loads but is these textboxes are empty. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your code sample is missing several `<` on your tags. If that's really what your code looks like, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: How about you read up about http get and post methods differences?
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Comment: "<" tags r missing cause i deleted them here cause it wouldnt let me post for some reason, they're there in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access those controls serverside, you'll need to add the `runat="server"` attribute to each of them.

Also, the `TextBox` type you're referencing is the ASP.NET control, which you aren't using. What you'd be using, once you add the `runat="server"` tags is [`HtmlInputText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext.aspx).

You can use the `TextBox` type by using the TextBox ASP.NET control instead of the `<input>` elements:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Value="Amy" />
```

If all your ASP.NET page is doing is processing the request from the form, then there's no need to reference any textbox or input controls - it won't be possible since they don't exist as ASP.NET controls. All you need to do is read the values from Request.QueryString.

If the intent is for the inputs to be visible and/or editable once they're on the ASP.NET page, I'd recommend moving the HTML form into your ASP.NET page.

Comment: why would i use <asp:textbox when my page is a .htm? first page is .htm and the values goto .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

it is not like this that webform functionate.

First, your input in your form needs to be server control: ex <`asp:TextBox runat="server" id="name" Text="value" />`

Then in your codebehind file you do not have to go through `Page.FindControl("YourInput")` but only `this.YourInput.Text`